# Positive, real, bounded sequence $(X_n)$. Prove that $\liminf \sqrt{X_n} = \sqrt{\liminf X_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Define $(X_n)$ to be a bounded sequence of real numbers such that $∀n∈ℕ, X_n ≥ 0$

Show that $\liminf \sqrt{X_n} = \sqrt{\liminf X_n}$

Side-question: $(X_n) ⊆ ℝ$?

How should I go about on this proof? I don't see a direct way and am wondering if I should first prove $\liminf \sqrt{X_n} \le \sqrt{\liminf X_n}$ and then $\liminf \sqrt{X_n} \ge \sqrt{\liminf X_n}$?

How do I start? If I consider $u ∈ S(\sqrt{X_n})$, a subsequence limit of $\sqrt{X_n}$, how to proceed?

Comment: To answer the side question, you should notice that sequence is not a set. *Components* of a sequence are arranged along the order of the natural numbers, whereas *elements* of a set have no order. Thus asking whether a sequence of a subset of some set has no meaning.

Comment: @HanulJeon ... continuity need not preserve order.

Comment: why a sequence is not a set?

Comment: @GEdgar You are right, I made a mistake '-'... The properties we need are both continuity and monotony.

Comment: @kmitov My comment has a subtle point. In set theory everything is a set. However, sequence of reals is *not* a subset of reals, because of the reason I explained; members of a sequence have an order, but elements of a set are not.

Comment: are the integers subset of reals?

Comment: @kmitov ℕ ⊆ ℤ ⊆ ℚ ⊆ℝ. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: but the integers are a sequence.

Comment: Sequence can be regarded as a function from the set of naturals to some set. (Formally, sequence is *defined* in that way.) Can we compare a function to $X$ and a subset of $X$ as subset relation?

Comment: @kmitov Yes, the set of integers is a subset of reals. The order I mentioned is about *how to arranged in the sequence*, not the order endowed with the structure of reals.

Comment: @kmitov We can find a sequence that has every integer as its member. However it does not mean that the set of integers is a sequence. I recommend to learn the precise concept of the set and the sequence.

Comment: ok. i will do .

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not for discussions...

**side question**

If I write $(X_n)$ for a sequence of reals, I do not mean the same thing as the set $\{X_n\}$ of reals.  This sequence
$$
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,\cdots
$$
(continuing with the value $1$) is not the same as this seeuence
$$
0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots
$$
(continuing to alternate).  These two sequences have different $\liminf$.  But of course the two sets we get from them are both $\{0,1\}$.